# Vuex: dispatch with array as argument

Tags: vuex

Is it possible to have an array in the payload of dispatch method in vuex ?

Below, I have a `table` name string, an `id` number, but the `path` array in the payload gives me the array length as a result.

```
this.$store.dispatch('DESTROY_ENTRY', { table, id, path }).then(response => {
  console.log(response)
}, error => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

===

After NikosM comment, I realized that if I set this:

```
this.$store.dispatch('DESTROY_ENTRY', { table, id, path2: { 'a':'foo', 'b':'bar' } })
```

I get this for `path`:

```
path2: {a: "foo", b: "bar"}
```

But it doesn't accept my `path` array.

Comment: what if you change the prop name? ie `{table:table, id:id, path2:path}`

Comment: @NikosM. it changes the key name, but I still get the array length as value.